# Drupal 7 Quiz Module - in which part of the code is a new quiz stored in the database?

Tags: drupal-7

In which part of the code is a new quiz stored in the database? What are the functions responsible for storing a new quiz in the database upon the submission of the form for creating a new quiz?

I'm trying to accomplish two things:

1. Timer per question
2. Dynamic question selection strategy

Drupal 7

Quiz Module 7.x-5.3

Comment: I think It's like a classical content type

Answer (score 0):

The quiz module offers the quiz content type. So there is no specific code storing the quiz in the database, as this is handled by drupal core. Some quiz specific data may partially be processed by quiz module functions, but without knowing why you are asking this question and what problem you are trying to solve, it is very difficult to point you in the correct direction.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish two things:
Timer per question and Dynamic question selection strategy

Comment: The Timer per question I would probably implement as a field which is only displayed as a hidden element somewhere and then add some js via a template file that displays the countdown. Depending on how tamperproof you want this to be, you may want to add verification in the submit handler of time passed between question generation and submission (for which you would have to store the question generation time in some manner). Dynamic question selection strategy is more difficult, you'd have to spend some time with the module code for that. Neither of these are beginner's topics, though.